# DB2 : How to resolve "SQL0206N "INVOICEDATE" is not valid in the context where it is used.SQLSTATE=42703" error

Tags: db2

In linux i connected to DB2 and trying to grab oldest invoice.
while using this below query it shows an error `SQL0206N  "INVOICEDATE" is not valid in the context where it is used.SQLSTATE=42703`

```
db2 "select min(INVOICEDATE) from RHA2";
```

How can I resove this error . any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess your column is actaully called e.g. `InvoiceDate` or some such mixed or lower case name , in which case, try `db2 'select min("InvoiceDate") from RHA2'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $ db2 "? sql206"
>
> SQL0206N  "" is not valid in the context where it is used.
>
> Explanation:
>
> This error can occur in the following cases:
>
> - For an INSERT or UPDATE statement, the specified column is not a    column of the table, or view that was specified as the object of the
>     insert or update.
> - **For a SELECT or DELETE statement, the specified column is not a    column of any of the tables or views identified in a FROM clause in
>
>     the statement.**
> - For an assignment statement, the reference name does not resolve to    the name of a column or variable.
> - When referencing a field in a row type variable, the reference name    does not resolve to the name of any field in the row type.
> - For an ORDER BY clause, the specified column is a correlated column    reference in a subselect, which is not allowed.
> - For a SELECT statement in a parameterized cursor constructor, the    reference to "" does not match a column or in-scope    variable.
>     Local variables and routine SQL parameters are not    considered in
>     scope for parameterized cursors.
> - For a standalone compound SQL (compiled) statement:
>
>   - The reference "" does not resolve to the name of a
>       column or local variable that is in scope.
>   - The condition name "" specified in the SIGNAL
>       statement has not been declared.
>   - When referencing a field in a row type variable, the reference
>       name does not resolve to the name of any field in the row type.
> - For a CREATE TRIGGER,CREATE METHOD,CREATE FUNCTION or CREATE    PROCEDURE statement:
>
>   - The reference "" does not resolve to the name of a
>       column, local variable or transition variable.
>   - The reference "" resolves to the name of a local
>       variable that is not available in the current scope.
>   - The condition name "" specified in the SIGNAL
>       statement has not been declared.
>   - When referencing a field in a row type variable, the reference
>       name does not resolve to the name of any field in the row type.
> - For a CREATE TRIGGER statement:
>
>   - A reference is made to a column of the subject table without
>       using
>       an OLD or NEW correlation name.
>   - The left hand side of an assignment in the SET
>       transition-variable
>       statement in the triggered action specifies an old transition
>       variable where only a new transition variable is supported.
> - For a CREATE FUNCTION statement with a PREDICATES clause:
>
>   - The RETURN statement of the SQL function references a variable
>       that is not a parameter or other variable that is in the scope of
>       the RETURN statement.
>   - The FILTER USING clause references a variable that is not a
>       parameter name or an expression name in the WHEN clause.
>   - The search target in an index exploitation rule does not match
>       some parameter name of the function that is being created.
>   - A search argument in an index exploitation rule does not match
>       either an expression name in the EXPRESSION AS clause or a
>       parameter name of the function being created.
> - For a CREATE INDEX EXTENSION statement, the RANGE THROUGH clause or    the FILTER USING clause references a variable that is not a parameter 
>     name that can be used in the clause.
> - For a parameterized cursor variable reference, a local SQL variable    or SQL parameter referenced in the select statement used in the
>     definition of a parameterized cursor variable is not available in the 
>     current scope.
> - For a period reference, the specified period is not in any of the    source or target tables or views of the statement.
>
> The statement cannot be processed.
>
> User response:
>
> Verify that the names are specified correctly in the SQL statement.
>   For a SELECT statement, ensure that all the required tables are named
>   in the FROM clause. For a subselect in an ORDER BY clause, ensure that
>   there are no correlated column references. If a correlation name is
>   used for a table, verify that subsequent references use the
>   correlation name and not the table name.
>
> For a CREATE TRIGGER statement, ensure that only new transition
>   variables are specified on the left hand side of assignments in the
>   SET transition-variable statement and that any reference to columns of
>   the subject table have a correlation name specified.
>
> For a standalone compound SQL statement, CREATE FUNCTION, CREATE
>   PROCEDURE, or CREATE TRIGGER statement, verify that the columns or
>   variables are available in the scope of the current compound SQL
>   statement.
>
> For a fullselect embedded in XQuery using the db2-fn:sqlquery
>   function, a reference within the fullselect must be one of the
>   following: a column in the context of the fullselect, a global
>   variable, or a parameter passed to the new SQL context using an
>   additional argument of the db2-fn:sqlquery function.
>
> sqlcode: -206
>
> sqlstate: 42703